# Missaligned tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix of nodes that I will then use as a grid for overlaying my real nodes on top of it, but for some reason the grid appears misaligned once I overlay something on top of it, or put some content inside of the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (table) [
        matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
        row  sep=1mm, column sep=1mm, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
        nodes = { draw, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm } ]
        {
        $Resc_1$ & & & & & & & & \\
        $Resc_2$ & & & & & & & & \\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I align the first column with the rest of the matrix?

Comment: Add `anchor=center` to the `nodes` options.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I've marked this question as a duplicate if you think I'm wrong, let me know.

Comment: @Ignasi: In my opinion, it is not a duplicate. My suggestion: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (table) 
[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
row  sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
nodes={draw,minimum width=10mm,minimum height=10mm,anchor=center}]
        {
        $Resc_1$ & & & & & & & & \\
        $Resc_2$ & & & & & & & & \\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: @BlackMild I think both questions show the same problem, empty and non empty nodes are not equally positioned when `matrix of nodes` is used. The reason is that `matrix of nodes` changes `anchor=center` to `anchor=base`, therefore we should revert this change in `nodes` options. Why do you think they are different questions? What does your code propose that is different from percusse's comment?

Comment: @Ignasi row sep and column sep should be changed.